# Where to start from with scraping/crawling in c++/c#?

Tags: c#, c++, client-server, web-scraping, web-crawler

First of all, I hope scraping is the right word for sending requests to an website from a desktop .exe and fetching data. If it is, what library or plugins should I use? Should I even use another language for doing this (like Java or something else?). 
I'd need some "hints" because I really dont know where to start from ...

Comment: I like ruby+nokogiri: http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/parsing_an_html_xml_document.html

Answer (score 1):

```
 If it is, what library or plugins should I use?
```

One of the most known scrapping tool for c# is

[Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Or you can just take a look  at google

[`abot`](https://code.google.com/p/abot/)

which  is an open source C# web crawler built for speed and flexibility

Comment: Can I get also search results for example, using the tools linked by you ?